# How to import multiple class objects from seperate folders?

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, python-packaging, module-packaging

I built a **python 2.7** application with the below directory structure for my relevant files. How do cal methods located in different folder locations?

```
Data-Wrangling-OpenStreetMap-data
 |
 +---- process_data
 |       |
 |       +---- __init__.py
 |       |
 |       +---- data_cleaner.py
 |
 +---- main_code.py
 |
 +---- audit _data
 |       |
 |       +---- __init__.py
 |       |
 |       +---- audit_file.py
```

I have succeeded in doing it correctly for one class referenced from main_code.py via the use of:

```
from process_data.data_cleaner import DataCleaner
```

However, if attempt a similar pattern for another class located in seperate folder referenced by main_code.py for via the use of the import statement

```
from audit_data.audit_file import AuditFile
```

**I get the error:**

> ImportError: No module named audit_data.audit_file

Any ideas as to what I may be overlooking and/or guidance on what further details I need to post to help find the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from process_data.data_cleaner import data_cleaner
```

as data_cleaner is the file name data_cleaner.py and the second one data_cleaner is a class defined in it.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, unfortunately, when I do that the one import that does work in my code then fails as well ie I now get
**ImportError: cannot import name data_cleaner**

Comment: My apologies, what you had stated was in fact correct...however my Class was named DataCleaner; when I use the following: `from process_data.data_cleaner import DataCleaner` it works.  ...However, when I reference the other Class located in a seperate folder its this class ie `from audit_data.audit_file import AuditFile` . that fails and returns the error msg: **ImportError: No module named audit_data.audit_file**

Answer (score 0):

The cause of my problem was a silly one; 
The folder containing the class I was calling was named **audit _file** whilst the folder I was calling within my code was **audit_file**

**What didnt work**
`from audit_data.audit_file import AuditFile`

**What worked**
`from audit _data.audit_file import AuditFile`

**For those reading this watch out for unintended spaces in your folder names**